# How can Google forms redirect to custom URL on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, google-forms

I am working with a WordPress site trying to embed Google Forms. Everything seemed to be working until I tried to redirect the form to a custom thank you page. The iframe code is working perfectly fine:

```
<iframe src="GOOGLE FORM EXAMPLE /viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="1050" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

However, when I entered the meta code which is meant to redirect, it worked once but now it loads the thank you page instantly when the form page is opened:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=www.EXAMPLE.com/ThankYou">
```

Which I definitely do not want, so the question is how can I rewrite this so the form page won't redirect until the person filling it out presses submit? I have a feeling this is an easy problem to solve but I have found nothing online and I am starting to feel really really stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Google **does not** support this.

also, `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url="www.EXAMPLE.com/ThankYou">` refreshes the page with the iFrame in it, so that wont work. **See Below:**

**Refrence**
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/90dJqCYl_fU/4OLrE6ykltIJ

**In that thread** there is a solution using JS but I'm not sure if it will work correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
    <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;"     
onload="if(submitted) {window.location='whateveryourredirectis.html';}"></iframe>
      <form action="YOUR-EMBEDDED-GOOGLE-SPREADSHEET-LINK" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" 
onsubmit="submitted=true;">
```

and place your google form link there. I have **not** tested this code.

Another workaround is not even using Google Forms at all, and creating an [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and using https://getform.org/ in your WordPress site.

Hopefully, I helped you out! Please let me know what happens afterward, and if it works, mark the correct answer.

Comment: I have seen this forum before and unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work with WordPress, but thank you.

Comment: Yea no problem! Have you tried the getform solution yet?

Comment: Its not my site, but I did send the suggestion to my boss and more than likely we will switch over to that or ninjaform

Comment: Cool. If it worked, can you mark it as correct? Also, if you need any more assistance, let me know and we can talk about it on discord (only option for me) **PS** if you need help setting it up im more than willing to give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Comment: How would this even work? Google Forms is within an iframe which you've just blanked out with your `display:none;` This logic does not make any sense since the actual form which is supposed to be embedded is now hidden. I know you referenced where you found this, but this has no means to display the form within the iframe.